# Laravel Call to undefined function Illuminate\View\Compilers\token_get_all()

Tags: php, laravel

I have AMPPS and just now tried installing Laravel on it using [this tutorial](http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Installing_Laravel_Framework). As soon as i created new project and tried to run it i got below error

```
FatalErrorException in BladeCompiler.php line 160: 
Call to undefined function Illuminate\View\Compilers\token_get_all()
```

I have no idea what is this error, I am totally new to laravel. 
I am using AMPPS, I tried php version 5.5 and 5.6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably don't install `Tokenizer PHP Extension`.
You can check it on `phpinfo` page

Comment: Ok dont know how, But i changed php version and then enabled disabled extentions listed in AMPPS docs and it worked. Thanks for answer though.

Comment: I have extension installed and active, but I get this error.

Comment: This answer lacks the most important information - how to install it. After installing php7.4 I had to add `extension=tokenizer.so` into `php.ini`

Comment: Also remember that if you're running PHP via FPM, you need to restart the server for the change to the configuration to actually propagate.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved with this command:

```
sudo phpenmod tokenizer
```

Then I restart the web server and PHP.

```
sudo system nginx restart

sudo system php7.4-fpm restart
```

**I used Nginx. If you use other web server such as Apache, use the command: sudo system nginx restart. And if you use a php version other than 7.4 replace it with your version.**